# Evaluate Expression in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have a SQL table like the following image

[image: link]

Here `Basic` and `HouseRent` column are of `varchar` type. I want to calculate the `Basic` and `HouseRent` from the `expression`. `Gross` and `Medical` already have the value.

I tried the following SQL but it shows

> Invalid column name GrossSalary and Medical

```
Create table #Results (ID int,Value varchar(max))
Declare @SQL varchar(max)=''
Select @SQL = @SQL+concat(',(',PolicyId,',cast(',Basic,' as varchar(max)))')From ProllSalaryPolicy
Select @SQL = 'Insert Into #Results Select * From ('+Stuff(@SQL,1,1,'values')+') N(ID,Value)'
```

Comment: SQL-Server is not Excel. This is an absolutely wrong approach... Read about [computed columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15) or create a VIEW returning your computed columns.

Comment: I know brother that it is a horrible design. I tried to explain them that lets keep the breakdown salary in percentage. But management wants `basic` and `Houserent` portion to be a expression.

Comment: Well, sometimes we have to live with bad decisions :-)  The problem here is, that you get **the feeling** of a **generic** approach. People will think, that any formula may be written into the cell and some magic action would compute the correct outcome. Obviously you know all this. So I can only wish you good luck :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably want try as this ([tested in SQL 2017 fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8de361dbda99597a9e70e87cc8b8bf29)):

```
Create table prollSalaryPolicy 
(ID int, 
GrossSalary float, 
Medical float, 
BasicExpression varchar(1000) 
);

Create table #Results (ID int,Value varchar(max));
```

```
Insert into prollSalaryPolicy (id, GrossSalary, Medical, BasicExpression)
values
(1, 13000,1400,'(GrossSalary-Medical)/1.5')
```

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max)='';
Select @SQL = @SQL + CONCAT (cast(id as varchar(3)),', ', BasicExpression) from prollSalaryPolicy;
Print @SQL;
select @SQL = 'Insert into #Results (ID, Value) select ' + @SQL + ' from  prollSalaryPolicy'
Print @SQL;
exec (@SQL);
```

Comment: Thanks mate your answer is correct. i just needed a little modification to save it with name.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to calculate the Basic and HouseRent column

If the formula doesn't change I suggest to create 2 more colums :
 The first BasicValue and the second HouseRentValue

and you can fill this 2 column by using this script

Update YourTable 
set BasicValue = (GrossSalary - Medical ) / Convert(Decimal(4,2),Right(basic,3))
set HouseRentValue = Basic * Convert(Decimal(4,2),Right( HouseRent,3))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create table ProllSalaryPolicy (
  PolicyId int not null,
  GrossSalary int,
  Medical int,
  Basic varchar(512),
  HouseRent varchar(512)
)

insert into ProllSalaryPolicy values(1, 13100, 1450,'(GrossSalary-Medical)/1.5', 'Basic*0.4')
insert into ProllSalaryPolicy values(3, 13100, 1450,'(GrossSalary-Medical)/1.4', 'Basic*0.5')

Create table #Results (ID int,Value varchar(max))
Declare @SQL varchar(max)=''

Select @SQL  = @SQL+' Insert Into #Results(Id, Value) Select '+cast(PolicyId as varchar(50))+', '+Replace(HouseRent,'Basic',Basic)+' FROM ProllSalaryPolicy where PolicyId = '+cast(PolicyId as varchar(50)) from ProllSalaryPolicy 

exec (@sql)

select * from #Results

drop table #Results

drop table ProllSalaryPolicy
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer i am trying this `sql` i will let you know the result.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below Query

```
Create Table #Sal (PolicyId varchar(10),GrossSalary float,Medical Float,Basic Varchar(1000),HouseRent varchar(100))
insert into #Sal

Values(1,13300,1450,'(GrossSalary-Medical)/1.5','Basic*0.4')
,(3,13100,1450,'(GrossSalary-Medical)/1.4','Basic*0.5')
select * from #Sal
Declare @Qry nvarchar(max)='select t1.PolicyId,sum(t1.GrossSalary),Sum(t1.Medical)
,Sum((t1.GrossSalary-t1.Medical)/1.5) from #Sal t1
Group by t1.PolicyId'

Exec sp_executeSql @Qry
```